# Type Error : No object named as orbit

Tags: jquery, css, css-frameworks

I am trying to use Foundation 3 from Zurb. A feature of theirs known as orbit slider, I am trying to use that. But I am getting this error and one more error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>
> Uncaught Type Error: Object [object Object] has no method 'Orbit'

Here my code:

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Mama's Kitchen</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/foundation.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.accordion.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.alerts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.buttons.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.forms.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.navigation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.reveal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #EE9A49">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="nine columns centered " >
                <img src="images/il_fullxfull.148292217.jpg" style="float: left" width="150px"  height="150px"/>
                <h3 style="font-family:  'Shadows Into Light Two', cursive;">Mama's Indian Kitchen</h3>
                <h5 style="font-family:  'Shadows Into Light Two', cursive;">Authentic Indian Food</h5>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="nine columns centered">

                <div id="featured">
                    <img src="images/528061_432208526817809_425531179_n.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/578889_431847450187250_114066073_n.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/579962_431846126854049_1905559928_n.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#featured').orbit();
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Loading `jquery.js` first (before the jquery plugins) should fix your issue

Comment: You are loading the foundation jquery plugins before jquery itself